# Laravel morphedByMany return all records by where condition and count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

```
Table 1: products: id, title, publish,created_at
Table 2: tags: id,name,created_at
Table 3: taggable: id,tag_id,taggable_type,taggable_id
```

I want get all distinct tags with count order by name.

I want it to return an array like this:

```
[
  ['name1'=>'value1','count'=>3],
  ['name2'=>'value2','count'=>3]
]
```

I have tried to do it like this:

```
$tags = \App\Tag::distinct()->where( function( $query ){
                   $query->whereHas('products', function ( $subquery ){
                       $subquery->where('publish', 1 );
                   })->get()->toarray();
                 })->withCount('products')->get()->toarray();
```

but it returns all (`product`) tags and all `products_count` values are 1 like this:

```
 [...],
 [▼
    "id" => 75
    "name" => "test1"
    "created_at" => "2018-10-30 18:49:51"
    "products_count" => 1
  ],
  [...]
  ...
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `tags`.*,

  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM `products`
   INNER JOIN `taggables` ON `products`.`id` = `taggables`.`taggable_id`
   WHERE `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`tag_id`
     AND `taggables`.`taggable_type` = ?) AS `products_count`
   FROM `tags`
   WHERE (EXISTS
         (SELECT *
          FROM `products`
          INNER JOIN `taggables` ON `products`.`id` =`taggables`.`taggable_id`
          WHERE `tags`.`id` = `taggables`.`tag_id`
            AND `taggables`.`taggable_type` = ?
            AND `publish` = ?))
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `->get()->toarray()` with `->toSql()` and post the result.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I did it.

Comment: How exactly is the result incorrect?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it return all duplicate tags with products_count = 1 like the image.

Comment: *All* tags have `products_count = 1`? What does "duplicate" mean? The same `id` multiple times?

Comment: I want that query return me all unique tags (not duplicated) with number of duplicate for that tag  (or with number of products that used that tag)

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) with some sample data and post the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`withCount('products')` must be called first and `distinct()` must be the last before `->get()->toArray()`.

Try this (not tested though):

```
$tags = \App\Tag::withCount('products')->where( function( $query ){
                   $query->whereHas('products', function ( $subquery ){
                       $subquery->where('publish', 1 );
                   })->get()->toArray();
                 })->distinct()->get()->toArray();
```